# How to serve file for URL with a given prefix?

Tags: swift, vapor

#### Context

I have been serving files via Vapor (v4) successfully with:

```swift
func configure(_ app: Application) throws {
   // ...
   app.middleware.use(FileMiddleware(publicDirectory: app.directory.publicDirectory))
   // ...
}
```

#### Problem

- This attempts to map any/every URL that would match a file within publicDirectory.
- How would one limit the "reach" of the `FileMiddleware` to only requests whose URL have a specific prefix? (say `/files/`)

As in, if I have `/Public/foobar.txt`, one would request it via `GET /files/foobar.txt` while `GET /foobar.txt` would NOT match anything.

#### Considered approaches

- My understanding is that `Middleware` is applied server-wide (affects every "route") and not a subset ... so this wouldn't work.
- Moving `/Public/foobar.txt` to `/Public/files/foobar.txt` is NOT a solution as I'm trying to limit URLs that can potentially get mapped to the file system...
- Redirecting `GET /files/foobar.txt` to `GET /foobar.txt` is also not acceptable.  Again, I need to limit the potential URLs which are mapped to the file system.

Comment: You can apply middleware to a subset of routes with a route group. So you could do
`let filesRoutes = app.grouped("files")` and then filesRoutes.grouped(FileMiddleware(...))` - if that works though I have no idea, worth a try!

Comment: @0xTim, I have just been trying the same suggestion but it doesn't seem possible to group the FileMiddleware in the same way as other middleware.

Comment: `FileMiddleware` thing is for debugging only. You shouldn't use it for production. For production you should configure nginx to serve your static files instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `FileMiddleware` will only work globally and not if attached to groups of routes as is usually the case with instances of middleware.

If you have a folder called Private in the project folder (i.e. the same folder holding your Public folder), then accessing files contained in it is straightforward:

```swift
public func configure(_ app: Application) throws {
    app.get("files", "**") { req -> Response in
        let filepath = req.parameters.getCatchall()
        let workPath = DirectoryConfiguration.detect().workingDirectory
        var fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: workPath)
            .appendingPathComponent("Private", isDirectory: true)
            .appendingPathComponent(filepath.joined(separator: "/"), isDirectory: false)
        return req.fileio.streamFile(at: fileURL.path)
    }
}
```

Assuming you are running this minimal project on `localhost:8080`, it will serve files via the URL:

http://localhost:8080/files/path/to/myFile.txt

EDIT

OP indicates flat files only. In the light of comment, made it work with arbitrary paths under `Private/`. I'll leave you to add action if file/path does not exist.

Comment: Interesting! Would this not require a flat directory structure?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of its validity, but I came up with the following after many more hours of searching for documentation:

```swift
app.get("files", "**") { req - > Response in
    // get rest of URL directly from `req.url.path`
    // ensure clean/secure URL and map it to file path using `DirectoryConfiguration`
    req.fileio.streamFile(at: "/path/to/files")
}
```

Aside some security concerns with making sure the URL is clean (i.e. not some "/../../" garbage), this should do I think.